# Hibernate 5 error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity class com.stockapi.application.model.OHLC

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-criteria

I want to retrieve a list of array for object OHLC. However, the console gives me an error like the topic. I should have declare an entity of OHLC somewhere in SessionFactory and it doesn't have a persistance.xml. The function works if it runs in local, but with the spring controller it returns the mentioned error.

function code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "candlestick", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody JsonArray findByTime(@RequestParam("fromDate") String fromDate, 
                                              @RequestParam("toDate") String toDate, 
                                              @RequestParam("interval") String interval) {
        Transaction transaction = null;

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd  HH:mm:ss");
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<OHLC> cr = cb.createQuery(OHLC.class);
            Root<OHLC> root = cr.from(OHLC.class);
            cr.select(root).where(cb.between(root.get("tickDate"), sdf.parse(fromDate), sdf.parse(toDate)));;

            Query<OHLC> query = session.createQuery(cr);
            List<OHLC> allOhlc = query.getResultList();
            session.close();

            return createArgsJsonArray(allOhlc);

        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           if (transaction != null) {
              transaction.rollback();
           }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

SessionFactory:

```
  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
      try {
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registryBuilder = 
            new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();

        Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<>();
        settings.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        settings.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1434;databaseName=stock;integratedSecurity=true");
        settings.put("hibernate.connection.username", "CORP\\01703057");
        settings.put("hibernate.connection.password", "");
        settings.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        settings.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

        registryBuilder.applySettings(settings);

        registry = registryBuilder.build();

        MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry)
            .addAnnotatedClass(OHLC.class);

        Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

        sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("SessionFactory creation failed");
        if (registry != null) {
          StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
      }
    }
    return sessionFactory;
  }
```

OHLC entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ohlc1min")
public class OHLC implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 779384126251139719L;
    private Long id;
    private String stock;
    private Date tickDate;
    private String source;

    private String date;
    private double open;
    private double high;
    private double low;
    private double close;
    private long volume;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "stock", nullable = false)
    public String getStock() {
        return stock;
    }
    public void setStock(String stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }
...
```

Comment: can you show us how OHLC class looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all serializing attributes and interfaces, also are all your class properties map correctly to table fields?